# parsing JSONArray with multiple values in android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSONfile like :

```
 { "data" :
     { "stop1" : [ "elem1", "elem2", "elem3", "elem4"],    
       "stop2" : [ "selem1", "selem2", "selem3", "selem4"] 
     } 
 }
```

For parsing this file I have written the following code:-

```
HashMap<String, String> stopList = new HashMap<>();
JSONObject dataJsonObj = (new JSONObject(json)).getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray busStopJsonObj, urlJsonObj;

busStopJsonObj = dataJsonObj .getJSONArray("stop1");
urlJsonObj = dataJsonObj .getJSONArray("stop2");

for (int i = 0; i < busStopJsonObj.length(); i++) 
   stopList.put(busStopJsonObj.getString(i), urlJsonObj.getString(i));
```

However i get an error as:

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"stop1":["elem1","elem2"
>    org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100) 
>    org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:500)

Comment: Seems JSON is invalid,http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: your json is wring there should be `,"stop2"`

Comment: that was a typo error in question.. Just corrected it.....

Comment: HashMap<String, String> stopList = new HashMap<String,String>();

Comment: the latter <String,String> can be neglected as it is been declared before.... @Aizen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your JSON is invalid. The correct JSON should be:

```
{"data": {
    "stop1": [
      "elem1",
      "elem2",
      "elem3",
      "elem4"
    ],
    "stop2": [
      "selem1",
      "selem2",
      "selem3",
      "selem4"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks people for help